# How to manage passwords and ConnectionStrings in a multi environment deployment using azure devops?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-devops

I have a web application, in the front end, I use asp.net framework and in the back end, I have a WCF service.

I want to have multi environments, one for staging and one for production.

I already succeed to deploy both the front and back end using azure DevOps, but I have difficulty figuring out the best way to store secrets(like passwords, connection string) knowing that I have multi env, because I don't want my secrets being visible to VCS, or when building. secrets should appear only in the release.

- I try first to use a secret file and upload web.config, so when the build is done I replace the web.config but it didn't look like a good idea because I don't want to re-upload the config file every time I change it.

I hope someone shares their experience of how he manages multi-environment deployment and hides secrets from VSC.

thanks.

Comment: Have you considered the [Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)? And if you use azure to host your web app you might not need to use secrets as all because there is the concept of [managed identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview)

Comment: from the answer below, I think we gonna use azure key vault, but still, I have an issue with replacing variables in web.config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of variables to store the secrets in Azure DevOps:-

You can click on variable tab while running your pipeline and store the secrets, passwords, connection strings in that variable for different stages, jobs and run the pipeline.

[image]

While running your Pipeline you can store your secrets or password in the variable like below and scope it to different stages too:-

[image]

[image]

And use it as an environment variable in the pipeline for different stages.

[image]

If you want to store the secrets commonly, You can also make use of variable group like below :-

[image]

You can mask the value to secure it

[image]

and in the variable script you can use the variable group directly to access the secrets:-

[image]

**You can also store your connection strings, secrets, password in azure key vault and then create azure key vault variable group in Azure DevOps pipeline like below**  :-

I have added one secret in the Azure key vault resource like below :-

[image]

Now, To access these secret value in Azure DevOps yaml pipeline refer below :-

```yaml
    trigger:
    - main
    steps:
    - task: AzureKeyVault@2
    inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'SID subscription(1)(<subscription-id>)'
    KeyVaultName: 'siliconvault'
    SecretsFilter: '*'
    RunAsPreJob: false
    - script : |
    echo $(dbpassword)
```

[image]

Make sure you give access permissions to the Azure DevOps service connection to access Key vault and the  **dbpassword will be encrypted when the pipeline runs**  like below :-

[image]

You can also create a variable group for storing this Azure Key vault secret in Azure DevOps:-

[image]

Reference :-

[Use Azure Key Vault secrets in Azure Pipelines - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

[Set secret variables - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-secret-variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbash)

Comment: hello, thank you for this demonstration it really helps, but I have one issue. how can I replace these variables in web.config?