# Use Azure devops release variables group in vue application

Tags: azure, vue.js, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, msal

I have inherited a project written in Angular with the right configuration to deploy to Azure devops.
I have been asked to make a 2.0 version of this project but this time written in Vue.
The project is already done and on localhost it works perfectly (with the login pulling against MSAL and all). The problem has been when deploying it. It's deployed correctly but I can't login.

This is because it uses the group variables that are in the release, that with Angular was already configured to access them but with Vue I can't do it.
In Angular there is a file called `env.js` in the root of the project that contains the following code:

```
(function (window) {
  window.__env = window.__env || {};
  window.__env.clientID = 'variable-id';
}(this));
```

Then I see that this file is loaded in `src/index.html`

```
<script src="env.js"></script>
```

And in `apply-deploy.yml` I have this:

```
args: ["-c", "sed -i -e s/variable-id/#{variable-id}#/g /usr/share/nginx/html/name-of-my-proyect/env.js ;nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]
```

Then in the config of MSAL, Angular project has this to load clientID:

```
window['__env']['clientID'];
```

So, I need to do similar in Vue.js

I have tried different things but none of them work, it always gives me undefined.
With the same configuration (using env.js) it doesn't work.

I have tried to use replace tokens in azure release, but maybe I have not idea how to do it correctly, but it doesn't work.

I have environments files like `.env` and `.env.prod` and there I have some constants like: `VUE_APP_NAME="XXXXX"`, so I have tried to add something like this:

```
VUE_APP_CLIENT_ID=#{variable-id}#
```

But it doesn't work. I have not idea how to do it.

Thanks a lot

[UPDATE]

I have `.env.production` file with this: `VUE_APP_CLIENT_ID=#{client-id}#` -> this client-id is a variable inside azure https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3CQk.png one of the variables I have crossed out.

And I have a `vsts-ci.yml` file and I have added this:

```
##### REPLACE TOKENS #####
  - task: qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@5
    displayName: "Replace tokens"
    inputs:
      targetFiles: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/.env.production"
```

I would like to access by process.env.VUE_APP_CLIENT_ID in my vue component and I would like to obtain the value inside azure variables.

Now I have deployed this code and pipeline returns:

```
##[warning]  variable not found: client-id
```

So I have not idea how to connect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried referring this [**Github sample**](https://github.com/sunilbandla/vue-msal-sample) by Sunil Bandla on **`vue+MSAL`** and I was able to access the `ClientID` in the evironment variable by creating **`.env`** file in my root project like below:-

**My Source code folder:-**

[image]

My **`.env`** file:-

```
clientID=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I have also install below package for the .env package to work successfully:-

```js
npm install --save-dev vue-cli-plugin-env
```

Referenced and edited the above **clientID** in **auth.service.js** from the Github sample above like below:-

```js
clientID: process.env.clientID
```

Complete **auth.service.js** Code:-

```js
import * as Msal from 'msal';

export default class AuthService {
  constructor() {
    let PROD_REDIRECT_URI = 'https://sunilbandla.github.io/vue-msal-sample/';
    let redirectUri = window.location.origin;
    if (window.location.hostname !== '127.0.0.1') {
      redirectUri = PROD_REDIRECT_URI;
    }
    this.applicationConfig = {
      clientID: process.env.clientID,
      graphScopes: ['user.read']
    };
    this.app = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(
      this.applicationConfig.clientID,
      '',
      () => {
        // callback for login redirect
      },
      {
        redirectUri
      }
    );
  }
  login() {
    return this.app.loginPopup(this.applicationConfig.graphScopes).then(
      idToken => {
        const user = this.app.getUser();
        if (user) {
          return user;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      },
      () => {
        return null;
      }
    );
  };
  logout() {
    this.app.logout();
  };
  getToken() {
    return this.app.acquireTokenSilent(this.applicationConfig.graphScopes).then(
      accessToken => {
        return accessToken;
      },
      error => {
        return this.app
          .acquireTokenPopup(this.applicationConfig.graphScopes)
          .then(
            accessToken => {
              return accessToken;
            },
            err => {
              console.error(err);
            }
          );
      }
    );
  };
}
```

**Output:-**

**I was able to Log in successfully like below:-**

[image]

Adding Environment variable is not required in the Release pipeline as I am using .env to retrieve the variable:-

[image]

Comment: Super thanks for your answer :) But one question, here: clientID=xxxxxxxxxxxxx, in the XXXXX you put the value of ID? Because I need to connect this clientID with one of this variables: https://ibb.co/VLk8tJr @siddheshdesai

Comment: Yes, Its a value of the ID. You can link it to the variable too and retrieve it in the .env file like $variableId . Refer my [answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75183222/how-to-manage-passwords-and-connectionstrings-in-a-multi-environment-deployment/75184944#75184944) here and [answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76813142/azure-devops-yaml-release-pipeline-variable-reference-not-working/76865332#76865332) > In answer2 I have set the variable in web.config with Powershell comnand, You can try the same method for your auth.service.js and add the variable value there

Comment: thansk for you answer!  But I'm not sure, maybe here:  $updatedContent = $configContent -replace '<Setting Name="yName" Value="".*', '<Setting Name="yName" Value="test" />' I need to put my azure variable? I don't understand well :(

Comment: I have tried to put my azure variable in this line but it donesn't work, I can't connect with them

Comment: I have update my question @SiddheshDesai

Comment: Okayyy, Checking

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, it is estimated that you have neither defined the **secret** `client-id` in your key vault, nor defined the **variable** `client-id`in the **build/YAML pipeline**(`vsts-ci.yml`).

`replacetoken@5` task will search the variable **name** (**client-id**) between `#{` and `#}` ; and then replace `#{varaibleName}#` in your selected file with the variable **value** that is defined in this YAML pipeline.

Since you use the **build/YAML** pipeline to replace `#{client-id}#` with its value, you need to either get the value from the secret `client-id` created in key vault, or define this variable `client-id` in this pipeline directly for value replacement.

Therefore, plesae consider either changing the variable **name** in the `.env.production` file as the secret name that is already added into the referenced key vault, or defining the variable `client-id` in the pipeline for value replacement. Kindly see the sample below to help us understand better.

- Original `.env.sample` file in my repo.
  [image]
- Define the variable `client-id` with the value of `xxxx-xxxx-xxxx` in the YAML pipeline and use `replacetokens@5` task to replace `#{client-id}#` with `xxxx-xxxx-xxxx` in `.env.sample` file.

```
variables:
  client-id: xxxx-xxxx-xxxx

steps:
- task: replacetokens@5
  inputs:
    targetFiles: '.env.sample'
    encoding: 'auto'
    tokenPattern: 'default'
    writeBOM: true
    actionOnMissing: 'warn'
    keepToken: false
    actionOnNoFiles: 'continue'
    enableTransforms: false
    enableRecursion: false
    useLegacyPattern: false
    enableTelemetry: true

- script: vim .env.sample
```

- Check the file after value replacement.
  [image]
- You can also create a **secret** `client-id` in key vault, link it to a variable group and reference it in this YAML pipeline.
  [image]

```
variables:
- group: DEV01-MIlabkv (DATAHUB)

steps:
- task: replacetokens@5
  inputs:
    targetFiles: '.env.sample'
    encoding: 'auto'
    tokenPattern: 'default'
    writeBOM: true
    actionOnMissing: 'warn'
    keepToken: false
    actionOnNoFiles: 'continue'
    enableTransforms: false
    enableRecursion: false
    useLegacyPattern: false
    enableTelemetry: true

- upload: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/.env.sample
```

[image]

- For the variable replacement sample in a release pipeline.
  [image]

Hope the information would help address your query.

Comment: Thanks @alvin-zhao I have used your answer and it's ok!!! :D